separately varying left and right y axes in rrdtool?
Is there any way to have the left and right y axes vary scales independently?  I'm using --right-axis 10:0 which is fine but what I really want is to be able to vary the right axis based on the data I am plotting against it, which I can compute with a CDEF, but I don't think I can use that CDEF in the right axis (the source just parses two doubles for that parm).  Is there any hack to do this?
Thanks,
Chris

Sorry, but this is not possible directly.  The dual-access support in RRDTool only extends as far as scale and shift; it does not have automatic scaling.
What you could do, though, is to take a two-step approach, and first retrieve the maximum value for the two variables, and from this calculate an optimal scaling ratio to use in a subsequent graph call.

Okay, so use rrdfetch to get the min/max and then set the rrdgraph command line from that?  I use a script anyway so this should be pretty easy.
